# Remote debugging of ASP.Net Core 2.2 + .Net framework under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, remote-debugging, iis-8

I have a particular setup which is giving me trouble in getting remote debugging to work.

ASP.Net Core 2.2 targeting full .NET framwork 4.7.2
Running under IIS 8.5, Out-of-Process

I am trying to remote debug in Visual Studio 2017. I can connect to the remote debugger, see the processes etc. There is no `dotnet.exe` running, just `w3wp.exe` and under that, the application `X.exe`

I can connect to the `w3wp.exe` but any breakpoints say they won't be hit as symbols are not loaded. I built/deployed with Debug and there is an `X.pdb` in the same location as `X.exe` both locally and remotely.

`Debug->Windows->Modules` is not much use to load symbols as all that is listed there are the standard `.dlls` which `w3wp.exe` loads. The app is an .exe, not a .dll module and so is not in the list and so I cannot load symbols manually.

I have tried connecting to `X.exe` directly but it just says it can't connect and to make sure the remote debugger is running (which it is, since I can connect easily to the `w3wp.exe` process).

I have tried coping everything (including the .exe and .pdb) to the same path on the remote (that is set in the debugging options). I have also tried running the remote debugger as the same user as the one running the local VS. Always the same result.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1 You must access at least one page of your ASP.NET Core web app, so as to trigger the actual Kestrel process.

Comment: It's a pure WebAPI, no pages per se ....

Comment: Even if you trigger an error page, that's still a page.

Comment: I think that's fine - I assume the Kestrel process is the `X.exe` (X is the name of the project) which runs under `w3wp.exe` as this only appears after some access, as you say. However, I can't connect to `X.exe` directly as mentioned. I can connect to `w2wp.exe` but then I get the symbol error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we could attach the w3wp.exe to remote debug the IIS asp.net core application. Make sure you attch the right worker process.

Besides, I suggest you could try to follow below settings to set the symbols in your visual studio 2017.

I suggest you could copy your local project’s bin folder path and add it into the symbol file. 
locations as below:
Example: `C:\Users\usernmae\source\repos\TestCore\bin\Debug\`

[image]

Details about how to remote debug the application, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/BrandoZh/IIS-Troubleshoot/wiki/Remote-debug-with-Visual-Studio).

Comment: Is the Symbol file location shown the path on the remote or local? I have added the location of both remote and local dirs in which `X.pdb` exists but still it complains that it cannot load symbols. For example, I added:
`c:\somedirs\bin\net472` (local path of `X.pdb`) and
`d:\somedirs` (remote path of `X.pdb`)